# How to merge text of two different dataframes by date?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two different dataframes, each of which contains different texts by month. What I want to do is merging the texts that have the same date in one single dataframe.

Let me take an example to clarify. This is *dataframe_A* where the third column (**Article**) contains some text for each date:

```
            Date            Title  Article
1  1 January 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_A_1
2 1 February 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_A_2
3    1 March 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_A_3
```

This is *dataframe_B* that contains **different** text but in the **same** date:

```
            Date            Title  Article
1  1 January 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_B_1
2 1 February 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_B_2
3    1 March 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_B_3
```

Now, I want to combine the text of **Article_topic_A_1** with the text of **Article_topic_B_1**, text of **Article_topic_A_2** with the text of **Article_topic_B_2**, and so on. For the same date (e.g.: 1 January 2000), I want to combine different articles (e.g.: Article_topic_A_1 and Article_topic_B_1). Basically, the final dataframe needs to look like this:

```
            Date            Title  Article
1  1 January 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article1
2 1 February 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article2
3    1 March 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article3
```

The third column will contain the merged texts that have been grouped by "date".

I tried to use *merge* and *subset* but I did not manage to do it.

Can you help me with it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `merge`, with the text for both separated by `,`.

```r
df_a <- data.frame(
  Date = c("1 January 2000", "1 February 2000", "1 March 2000"),
  Title = rep("PRESS CONFERENCE", 3),
  Article = c("Article_topic_A_1", "Article_topic_A_2", "Article_topic_A_3")
)

df_b <- data.frame(
  Date = c("1 January 2000", "1 February 2000", "1 March 2000"),
  Title = rep("PRESS CONFERENCE", 3),
  Article = c("Article_topic_B_1", "Article_topic_B_2", "Article_topic_B_3")
)

df <- merge(df_a, df_b, by = c("Date", "Title"))
df$Article <- paste(df$Article.x, df$Article.y, sep = ", ")
df <- df[, !(names(df) %in% c("Article.x", "Article.y"))]
df
#>              Date            Title                              Article
#> 1 1 February 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_A_2, Article_topic_B_2
#> 2  1 January 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_A_1, Article_topic_B_1
#> 3    1 March 2000 PRESS CONFERENCE Article_topic_A_3, Article_topic_B_3
```